# Using Multiple Regular Expressions: Print One Match at a Time in Order They are Seen

Tags: java, regex

Given a string, I want to match tokens in the order in which they are scanned rather than printing all matches of a particular type of token out-of-order via a loop.

Currently, I iterate over an array of Strings in a for-each loop. I have Regexes that capture all the necessary tokens, but not in the order they are seen.

Here is what I have. A for-each loop call the `findTokens` function that finds all of that token type. This is wrong because like this it findsTokens by their Regex match rather than the order in which they came.

```
for(String line: lines) {
...
findTokens(line, keyword);
findTokens(line, identifier);
findTokens(line, number);
}
```

Here is my findTokens function. It takes in a string and a Regex. It checks if the Regex parameter equals one of the Regex declarations (not shown).

```
public static void findTokens(String str, String regex) {
        String keyword = "(else)+|(if)+|(int)+|(return)+|(void)+|(while)+|(main)+";
        String identifier = "\\b(?!(else)|(if)|(int)|(return)|(void)|(while)|(main))\\b[a-zA-Z]+";
        String number = "[\\d]+";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        if (regex.equals(keyword) ) {
            while ( matcher.find() ) { System.out.println("Keyword: " + matcher.group()); }
        } else if ( regex.equals(identifier) ) {
            while ( matcher.find() ) { System.out.println("ID: " + matcher.group()); }
        } else if ( regex.equals(number) ) {
            while ( matcher.find() ) { System.out.println("NUM: " + matcher.group()); }
        }
    }
```

Expected output:

```
INPUT: int g 4 cd int u int v
keyword: int
ID: g
NUM: 4
ID: cd
keyword: int
ID: u
keyword: int
ID: v
```

Actual output:

```
INPUT: int g 4 cd int u int v
keyword: int
keyword: int
keyword: int
ID: g
ID: cd
ID: u
ID: v
NUM: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them in one big regex, like this:

```
package test;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = Files.readString(Paths.get("src/main/java/test/Test.java"));

        String keyword = "\\b(?:else|if|int|return|void|while|for|package|import|public|protected|private|static|class|throws)\\b";
        String identifier = "\\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\\b";
        String number = "-?\\b[\\d]+\\b";
        String regex = "(" + keyword + ")|(" + identifier + ")|(" + number + ")";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        for (Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
            if (m.start(1) != -1)
                System.out.println("Keyword: " + m.group());
            else if (m.start(2) != -1)
                System.out.println("Identifier: " + m.group());
            else
                System.out.println("Number: " + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

The code uses it's own source code as a test, so the output is:

```
Keyword: package
Identifier: test
Keyword: import
Identifier: java
Identifier: nio
Identifier: file
Identifier: Files
Keyword: import
Identifier: java
Identifier: nio
Identifier: file
Identifier: Paths
Keyword: import
Identifier: java
Identifier: util
Identifier: regex
Identifier: Matcher
Keyword: import
Identifier: java
Identifier: util
Identifier: regex
Identifier: Pattern
Keyword: public
Keyword: class
Identifier: Test
Keyword: public
Keyword: static
Keyword: void
Identifier: main
Identifier: String
Identifier: args
Keyword: throws
Identifier: Exception
Identifier: String
Identifier: input
Identifier: Files
Identifier: readString
Identifier: Paths
Identifier: get
Identifier: src
Identifier: main
Identifier: java
Identifier: test
Identifier: Test
Identifier: java
Identifier: String
Identifier: keyword
Identifier: b
Keyword: else
Keyword: if
Keyword: int
Keyword: return
Keyword: void
Keyword: while
Keyword: for
Keyword: package
Keyword: import
Keyword: public
Keyword: protected
Keyword: private
Keyword: static
Keyword: class
Keyword: throws
Identifier: b
Identifier: String
Identifier: identifier
Identifier: b
Identifier: a
Identifier: zA
Identifier: Z
Identifier: a
Identifier: zA
Identifier: Z0
Number: -9
Identifier: b
Identifier: String
Identifier: number
Identifier: b
Identifier: d
Identifier: b
Identifier: String
Identifier: regex
Identifier: keyword
Identifier: identifier
Identifier: number
Identifier: Pattern
Identifier: pattern
Identifier: Pattern
Identifier: compile
Identifier: regex
Keyword: for
Identifier: Matcher
Identifier: m
Identifier: pattern
Identifier: matcher
Identifier: input
Identifier: m
Identifier: find
Keyword: if
Identifier: m
Identifier: start
Number: 1
Number: -1
Identifier: System
Identifier: out
Identifier: println
Identifier: Keyword
Identifier: m
Identifier: group
Keyword: else
Keyword: if
Identifier: m
Identifier: start
Number: 2
Number: -1
Identifier: System
Identifier: out
Identifier: println
Identifier: Identifier
Identifier: m
Identifier: group
Keyword: else
Identifier: System
Identifier: out
Identifier: println
Identifier: Number
Identifier: m
Identifier: group
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! One last thing if possible: how would I catch any token that is NOT either a keyword, an identifier, or a a number? Could I just use an else, or would I have to make a second combined regex? If so, would I have to use a negation inside each group, or just negate the condition in an else if statements?

Comment: @A.Sultan *"Could I just use an else, or would I have to make a second combined regex"* No, you'd extend the one already being used, adding a 4th option. However, you should seriously consider using a Java parser instead of regex.